# NSURLSessionDataTask call not working in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am executing following code when app is **not running** after click on "Actionable notification" button.i enabled background mode,remote-notification.

```
//base url is changed for privacy purpose
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/engine/auth/tx", [SharedData getGatewayURL]]]
                                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                                   timeoutInterval:HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                NSString *encodedXML = [encrypted urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", REQUEST_PARAMETER_NAME, encodedXML];
                [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


               NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

                NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


               //Handle response


                  }];
            [postDataTask resume];
```

//Delegate

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
        if([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"211.23.34.234"]){
            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
        }
    }
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];

}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes {

}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

}
```

> (I have shown here demo server url not actual)

Can we use NSURLSessionDataTask for executing background task when app is suspended or closed?

This code is perfectly working for **Server URL** ex. https://211.23.34.234/engine/auth/tx

But when i change **Server URL** to https://demo.tes.com/engine/auth/tx
not working.

Whats wrong with NSURLSessionDataTask ?

Is this due to **static IP 211.23.34.234** ? why it same code not working with https://demo.tes.com/engine/auth/tx ? (This server url can change dynamically) any help will much appreciated.

How to fix this?

**Note:**: setting delegate to "nil" of NSURLSessionDataTask will work for https://demo.tes.com/engine/auth/tx server but not https://211.23.34.234/engine/auth/tx

How to make it work at both server?

Comment: what is the response data you're getting?

Comment: No response from server. it in backgrund when app closed.

Comment: @RonakChaniyara. link is demo, not show for privacy purpose.

Comment: Did you check the error object in your call back params?

Comment: @Suresh. Nothing in error. and response as well

Comment: If you pass the IP and it worked, but not when you use the domain, there's something wrong with your DNS settings, not the `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai. thank for good suggestion.what could i check? i seen control until making http call but i never gone inside completionHandler.

Comment: use commands like `dig domain.com` to see what went wrong

Comment: Also if you are using HTTPs, make sure the SSL cert is valid for that domain, or it will not work by default either

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai. server team telling me.they have valid ssl cert. is anything need to do from myside for ssl?

Comment: I think you will have to post more info, such as the NSURLResponse when it's not working or error you got. There's not much we can work on in your question above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118318/discussion-between-avijit-nagare-and-zhi-wei-cai).

Comment: I think you can just update the question so others can help too.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai. updated question. setting dalegate to nil work for demo but not IP address server(ssl issue).

Comment: I meant the actual response data of both NSURLSessionDataTask, not more source code. We don't know what "not working" means. We have to see the response/error data.

Comment: Fixed. issue was in delegate method. which restrict completion handler for demo server.

Comment: Please enter the correct answer as an answer, and marked it as answered, so people will not read through a long post only to find it was already solved.

Comment: @OwenHartnett. put my answer.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. issue was in delegate method. which restrict completion handler for demo server.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
  //  if([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"211.23.34.234"]){    
            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
   //     }
    }
}
```

I was only allowed to auth fixed ip challenge authentication so commenting if condition works fine.